# Merging tags in Devdemon tagger simply deletes the tags in question - no merging occurs

Tags: tags, devdemon-tagger

When attempting to merge tags via the **Devdemon Tagger** instructions

> "To Merge tags separate each tag_id by a comma, the first tag_id being
>   the merged tag,"

it appears to simply delete all tags besides the first one. They do not get merged into the first tag.

Comment: Was there ever a resolution to this issue?